# Why doesn't div start after previous div?

Tags: css, html

I'm modifying the header portion of a WordPress theme and I'm trying to nest a couple divs within another div. I'm not very experienced with HTML/CSS, but what I'm observing seems weird to me.

My code looks like this:

```
<div class="extras">
    <div id="search"> 
        <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="http://mentatescholars.com/" >
            <input type="search" placeholder="Search" value="" name="s" id="s" />
            <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
        </form>
    </div><!-- end #search -->
    <div class="phone-number">
        <div class="phone-number-main">1-885-MENTATE</div>
        <div class="phone-number-sub">1-885-636-8283</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in the picture I have the `phone-number` div selected with Firefox's inspector (selecting `extras` looks the same). What strikes me as odd is why it's starting at the top of the `extras` div and not after the `search` div. `search` even has a set height of 40px.

[image: My search box and the phone number]

If I select the third div, then the it shows the div starting right after the previous div.

[image: Selecting the third div behaves like I would think]

What also strikes me as odd is how, while the top of the `phone-number-main` div is flush with `extras`, the text shifts down perfectly without me doing anything.

My question is this: How can I make it so that the `phone-number` div starts right after the `search` div?

Here's the site, if you want to look at it: http://mentatescholars.com/.

Comment: We'll need to see some CSS to go with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#search` is floated and the `.phone-number` isn't.
If you add `clear:both` to the `.phone-number` `<div />` you will see the correct layout.

`float` removes elements from the flow of the document. Check uot this link for more info: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-floats-101/

Comment: gonna post this, but i'm late!

Comment: @gamehelp16 You can always upvote an answer if you know it is correct.

Comment: Man I don't know what I'd do without this site... Thanks!

Comment: I tried using `clear:both` on one of the elements before, but I must have been applying it to the wrong one...

Answer (score 1):

that is because you have floated element. your "search" div is floated and has no clear. Use `clear:both` in the CSS of the phone-number element and it will work fine

And if you want the number to be right after `search` make the height of `search` 30px and get rid of the submit button's margin bottom.

Answer (score 0):

make #search block smaller by reducing height, lets say to 30px.

Comment: I should do that shouldn't I... And add a bottom margin.